# Create a constant based on subroutine argument

Tags: fortran

I have the following piece of code that splits the vector `x` into several arrays.

```
subroutine split(n, x, r, v, p, t)
    implicit none
    integer, intent(in) :: n
    double precision, intent(in) :: x(n)

    integer, parameter :: m = (n + 6) / 10
    ! problem here             1
    double precision, intent(out) :: r(3, m - 1)
    double precision, intent(out) :: v(3, m - 1)
    double precision, intent(out) :: p(3, m)
    double precision, intent(out) :: t(m)
    ! code
end subroutine split
```

This code does not compile with the message

```
Error: Parameter 'n' at (1) has not been declared or is a variable, which does not reduce to a constant expression
```

The code compiles fine if I manually change all `m` to `(n + 6) / 10` but I am seeking a more elegant approach.

As an alternative approach I've rewritten the code as

```
subroutine splitcore(n, m, x, r, v, p, t)
    implicit none
    integer, intent(in) :: n, m
    double precision, intent(in) :: x(n)
    double precision, intent(out) :: r(3, m - 1)
    double precision, intent(out) :: v(3, m - 1)
    double precision, intent(out) :: p(3, m)
    double precision, intent(out) :: t(m)
    ! code
end subroutine splitcore

subroutine split(n, x, r, v, p, t)
    implicit none
    integer, intent(in) :: n
    double precision, intent(in) :: x(n)

    integer :: m
    double precision, intent(out) :: r(3, *)
    double precision, intent(out) :: v(3, *)
    double precision, intent(out) :: p(3, *)
    double precision, intent(out) :: t(*)

    m = (n + 6) / 10

    call splitcore(n, m, x, r, v, p, t)
end subroutine split
```

Comment: You can not initialize constants using the values of variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array specifications for array declarations in subprograms are permitted to be specification expressions.

A specification expression can include a reference to a pure function.  You can use such a pure function to factor out the effective calculation of `m`.

To be considered pure in its scope of use, an explicit interface for a pure function must be accessible.  The simplest way of providing such an explicit interface is to put the function in a module (which, if `split` was already in such a module, could be the same module).

```
module m_mod
  implicit none
contains
  pure function m(n)
    integer, intent(in) :: n
    integer :: m
    m = (n + 6) / 10
  end function m
end module m_mod

subroutine split(n, x, r, v, p, t)
  use m_mod
  implicit none
  integer, intent(in) :: n
  double precision, intent(in) :: x(n)

  double precision, intent(out) :: r(3, m(n) - 1)
  double precision, intent(out) :: v(3, m(n) - 1)
  double precision, intent(out) :: p(3, m(n))
  double precision, intent(out) :: t(m(n))
  ...
```

In terms of the original code - the initializer for a variable, constant or type parameter has to be a constant expression - effectively something that the compiler can evaluate at compile time.  A constant expression has more restrictions on it than a specification expression - for example it cannot reference the value of a variable - because variables are not constants.

Rather than an explicit shape array, the dummy variables in the `split` subroutine could perhaps be made assumed shape (declared with `(:)` or `(:,:)`, as appropriate for the rank.  The specification of the shape of the array is then taken "(assumed") from the shape of the actual arguments, no shape calculations need be done in subroutine `split` at all.

Use of a subroutine with assumed shape dummy arguments requires an explicit interface for the procedure to be accessible in the scope where the procedure is referenced.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. You simply have to use `(n + 6) / 10` instead of `m`. Fortran does not allow you to define any intermediate computations before the  array declarations.

You wouldn't even need a constant (parameter) just a variable would have been sufficient. But it is not allowed.

If it were a variable and not a constant:

Initializers must be constant expressions. A value of a dummy argument (here `n`) is not a constant expression, it only gets value at run-time when the procedure is called.

Please note that any initialization makes the entity save and only happens once at the start of the program. It does not happen on every invocation of the procedure.

Comment: Alternatively, `associate` construct can be use to reduce the clutter.

Comment: @Wildcat, not in the context of the question where the value is to be used as a specification expression for explicit shape dummy arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The problem, in fact, has *nothing* to do with array declarations. The following simple snippet

```
subroutine split(n, x, r, v, p, t)
    implicit none

    integer, intent(in) :: n
    double precision, intent(in) :: x(n)
    integer :: m = (n + 6) / 10
end subroutine split
```

won't compile as well. So, even if `m` is declared as a variable, it can not be initialized by the `(n + 6) / 10` expression. The problem is that `(n + 6) / 10` is not a constant expression since it contains a variable `n`.

---

It is certainly possible to declare variable `m` first and assign the value of `(n + 6) / 10` expression to it later:

```
subroutine split(n, x, r, v, p, t)
    implicit none

    integer, intent(in) :: n
    double precision, intent(in) :: x(n)
    integer :: m

    m = (n + 6) / 10
end subroutine split
```

This can be used, for instance, to allocate the corresponding arrays (that has to be declared as allocatable, of course):

```
subroutine split(n, x, r, v, p, t)
    implicit none

    integer, intent(in) :: n
    double precision, intent(in) :: x(n)
    integer :: m

    double precision, dimension(:, :), allocatable, intent(out) :: r
    double precision, dimension(:, :), allocatable, intent(out) :: v
    double precision, dimension(:, :), allocatable, intent(out) :: p
    double precision, dimension(:), allocatable, intent(out) :: t

    m = (n + 6) / 10
    allocate (r(3, m-1))
    allocate (v(3, m - 1))
    allocate (p(3, m))
    allocate (t(m))
    ! code
end subroutine split
```